# Undefined Variables and warning session cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Guy sorry for this newbie question
Because i'm new in php programming..
This is my Question..
I follow This [tutorials](http://edrackham.com/php/php-login-script-tutorial/) but I Got many error..
All error is undefined
I Don't Know how to fixed it..
any advise or suggestion..
thanks in advance...

```
   <?php  
include_once('config.php');  

// Reset errors and success messages  
$errors = array();  
$success = array();  

// Login attempt  
if(isset($_POST['loginSubmit']) && $_POST['loginSubmit'] == 'true'){  
    $loginEmail = trim($_POST['email']);  
    $loginPassword  = trim($_POST['password']);  

    if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-] (.[_a-z0-9-] )*@[a-z0-9-] (.[a-z0-9-] )*(.[a-z]{2,3})$", $loginEmail))  
        $errors['loginEmail'] = 'Your email address is invalid.';  

    if(strlen($loginPassword) < 6 || strlen($loginPassword) > 12)  
        $errors['loginPassword'] = 'Your password must be between 6-12 characters.';  

    if(!$errors){  
        $query  = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail) . '" AND password = MD5("' . $loginPassword . '") LIMIT 1';  
        $result = mysql_query($query);  
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){  
            $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
            $query = 'UPDATE users SET session_id = "' . session_id() . '" WHERE id = ' . $user['id'] . ' LIMIT 1';  
            mysql_query($query);  
            header('Location: index.php');  
            exit;  
        }else{  
            $errors['login'] = 'No user was found with the details provided.';  
        }  
    }  
}  

// Register attempt  
if(isset($_POST['registerSubmit']) && $_POST['registerSubmit'] == 'true'){  
    $registerEmail = trim($_POST['email']);  
    $registerPassword = trim($_POST['password']);  
    $registerConfirmPassword    = trim($_POST['confirmPassword']);  

    if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-] (.[_a-z0-9-] )*@[a-z0-9-] (.[a-z0-9-] )*(.[a-z]{2,3})$", $registerEmail))   
        $errors['registerEmail'] = 'Your email address is invalid.';  

    if(strlen($registerPassword) < 6 || strlen($registerPassword) > 12)     
        $errors['registerPassword'] = 'Your password must be between 6-12 characters.';  

    if($registerPassword != $registerConfirmPassword)  
        $errors['registerConfirmPassword'] = 'Your passwords did not match.';  

    // Check to see if we have a user registered with this email address already  
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($registerEmail) . '" LIMIT 1';  
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)   
        $errors['registerEmail'] = 'This email address already exists.';  

    if(!$errors){  
        $query = 'INSERT INTO users SET email = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($registerEmail) . '",  
                                                                        password = MD5("' . mysql_real_escape_string($registerPassword) . '"),  
                                                                        date_registered = "' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"';  

        if(mysql_query($query)){  
            $success['register'] = 'Thank you for registering. You can now log in on the left.';  
        }else{  
            $errors['register'] = 'There was a problem registering you. Please check your details and try again.';  
        }  
    }  

}  
?>  



<form class="box400" name="loginForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">  
    <h2>Login</h2>  
    <?php if($errors['login']) print '<div class="invalid">' . $errors['login'] . '</div>'; ?>  

    <label for="email">Email Address</label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($loginEmail); ?>" />  
    <?php if($errors['loginEmail']) print '<div class="invalid">' . $errors['loginEmail'] . '</div>'; ?>  

    <label for="password">Password <span class="info">6-12 chars</span></label>  
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />  
    <?php if($errors['loginPassword']) print '<div class="invalid">' . $errors['loginPassword'] . '</div>'; ?>  

    <label for="loginSubmit">&nbsp;</label>  
    <input type="hidden" name="loginSubmit" id="loginSubmit" value="true" />  
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />  
</form>  

<form class="box400" name="registerForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">  
    <h2>Register</h2>  
    <?php if($success['register']) print '<div class="valid">' . $success['register'] . '</div>'; ?>  
    <?php if($errors['register']) print '<div class="invalid">' . $errors['register'] . '</div>'; ?>  

    <label for="email">Email Address</label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($registerEmail); ?>" />  
    <?php if($errors['registerEmail']) print '<div class="invalid">' . $errors['registerEmail'] . '</div>'; ?>  

    <label for="password">Password</label>  
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />  
    <?php if($errors['registerPassword']) print '<div class="invalid">' . $errors['registerPassword'] . '</div>'; ?>  

    <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>  
    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" value="" />  
    <?php if($errors['registerConfirmPassword']) print '<div class="invalid">' . $errors['registerConfirmPassword'] . '</div>'; ?>  

    <label for="registerSubmit">&nbsp;</label>  
    <input type="hidden" name="registerSubmit" id="registerSubmit" value="true" />  
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />  
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Hi I Dont Know What is the error
please guide me..

Comment: Yet another tutorial (I use the term loosely) that should be removed from teh internetz.

Comment: In fact, I [told](http://edrackham.com/php/php-login-script-tutorial/#comment-7385) him so.

Answer (score 0):

If you got an on-screen error message (such as "undefined variable"), that will of course send output to the browser. What happens is that when the first output (tags or text) gets sent to the browser, the accumulated HTTP "headers" get flushed out to the browser first. Once that happens, you're not allowed to send any more headers for this page. The session cache limiter is sent as a header, so there is an error message that it can't be sent (due to the headers already having been sent, due to the text being sent to the browser, due to the error).

Short form: fix the undefined variables, and the session cache limiter error will go away.